# View another file structure then actual in WebStorm

Tags: file, maps, webstorm, display

Is it possible to have another view of the file structure then the actual running thing?
I cant change the file structure, because reasons...

Real:
This is the running file hierarchy.

```
 folder1
 folder2
 folder3
```

Wanted: This is how I want it to be displayed

```
parentfolder1
  folder1
  folder2

parentfolder2
  folder3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature in WebStorm, please follow [IDEABKL-6196](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6196) for updates.
You can use Favorites as a workaround, as it's suggested in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6196#comment=27-287102